# How to take only(.*)

Tags: python

I have a loop in python and in every iteration the program is reading text from the console. In this text there is an Id of characters. The message that I am reading is "Your project is ready. Your ID: dfgdfgfd" So the id will be different in every iteration. After every iteration the ID should go to a list outside the loop. I am trying this, but i think that there is a better way, just to take the ID in (.*) and to append it in a list of ID's, not to take the line and to split it and to take the [6], just to take the Id and to append it.

```
import os
import sys
import re

ListOfProjects={projectA, projectB, projectC, projectE}
List_Of_Ids=[]
for x in ListOfProjects:
    IdFullText=sys.stdin.readline()
    Id=re.compile(r'Your project is ready. Your ID: (.*)')
    matches = Id.finditer(IdFullText)
    List_Of_Ids.append(Matches)
```

I want to take in a list only the id, that is different in every iteration. The sentence "Your project is ready. Your ID:" is always the same, but the id in the () will be different every time, like "dfsdf" or 'dsgfsdvc'. I need only this chars

Comment: So, you want to read text from the standard input and append that to a list, am I correct?

Comment: Almost, I want to take in a list only the id, that is different in every iteration. The sentence "Your project is ready. Your ID:" is always the same, but the id in the () will be different every time, like "dfsdf" or 'dsgfsdvc'. I need only this chars

Comment: What is `projectA, projectB, projectC, projectE` ? Are they string?

Comment: They are strings

Answer (score 0):

There are of course multiple solutions to such a problem.

## Using split()

As you suggested, one could split sentence based on spaces and take the last word, e.g:

```
ListOfProjects={projectA, projectB, projectC, projectE}
List_of_Ids=[project.split()[-1] for project in ListOfProjects]
```

Here you iterate over the `ListOfProjects`, split each `project` based on spaces and take the last word, which will be the ID.

## Using String indexing

As every sentence starts with 'Your project is ready. Your ID: ', i.e. 32 characters, you could simply take everything after the first 32 characters:

```
ListOfProjects={projectA, projectB, projectC, projectE}
List_of_Ids=[project[32:] for project in ListOfProjects]
```

Where project[32:] takes the string project and removes the first 32 characters.

## Using String replace

Another solution would be to replace the first part of the string with an empty string:

```
ListOfProjects={projectA, projectB, projectC, projectE}
List_of_Ids=[project.replace("Your project is ready. Your ID: ", "") for project in ListOfProjects]
```

## Using a regular expression

```
import re

ListOfProjects={projectA, projectB, projectC, projectE}
List_of_Ids=[re.sub("Your project is ready. Your ID: ", "", project) for project in ListOfProjects]
```

Here `re.sub("Your project is ready. Your ID: ", "", project)` replaces the text `"Your project is ready. Your ID: "` with the empty string `""` for the string variable `project`.

Comment: Thank you, Thijs, I have tried this, but I want to make it with regex.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will return a list of values that match the regex. In your case, it should return a list with only one item.

```
_str = 'Your project is ready. Your ID: A12345'    
re.findall(r'^Your project is ready. Your ID: (.*)$',_str)
#returns ['A12345']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
import re

if __name__=='__main__': 
    matches = re.findall('(?i)your\s*project\s*is\s*ready\.\s*your\s*id:\s*(.*)', "Your project is ready. Your ID:MixCaseID\nYour project is ready. Your ID:1234566\nYour project is ready. Your ID:lowercaseid\nYour project is ready. Your ID:UPPERCASEID\nYour project is ready. Your ID:PROJ-0001")
    for m in matches:
        print(m)
```

results in:

```
MixCaseID
1234566
lowercaseid
UPPERCASEID
PROJ-0001
```

Here:

```
(?i)   =  Case insensitive match
\s*    =  whitespace zero or more times
```

If the whole text 'Your project is ready. Your ID: MixCaseID' is not needed you can shorten your regex by excluding pattern before 'your\s*id:'. It will then look for ids that appear next to 'Your ID:'.